# What was the the original level cap on Baldur's Gate 2?

Tags: baldurs-gate-2

I know that the newest Baldur's Gate 2 EE has a level cap of 40 and I believe in BG1 it was like 7. What was the original cap for Baldur's Gate 2 (before the expac/EE revamp)?

Comment: The caps were based on exp, not level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Studoku](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/53291/studoku) already mentioned the caps were based on exp. It is important because different classes gain levels at different XP tresholds, not to mention dual and multiclassing which require some calculations. Writing out what levels exactly will that translate to is probably beyond the scope of this site, it's best to look it up somewhere else (like [this chart collection](http://baldursgate.wikia.com/wiki/Experience_tables)).

Also, it might be good to know that EE did not change the level-caps, it just comes bundled along with the expansions.

In BG1 the original cap was **89,000**, which was enough for levels 7-8

BG1 expansion, Tales of the Sword Coast upped it to **161,000** - enough for levels 8-10.

BG2 had it at **2.95 million**, which translates to levels 14(!)-21.

BG2 expansion, Throne of Bhaal upped it to **8 million** - enough for levels 31-40 (quite cleanly at that - Druids and arcane casters end at 31, the rest at 40). If I remember correctly however, getting to the cap here was very hard (requires intimate knowledge of all the possible xp sources).

Comment: Not to mention putting your skill point and attributes in the right order to get there.